# can SEP contribution be made more than one time for same year

Tags: united-states, ira, small-business, sep-ira

Can a small employer make contribution to SEP similar to 401K with each pay check/1099 or at end of the year for previous year. So for example for 2021 contributions, can one give 10% in January 2022, 10% in Feb 2022 and 5% in March 2022?

Comment: Yes, you can do multiple contributions.